# custom form validation annotation not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, bean-validation

I created a custom form validation annotation, to check if the date filled in the form is in the format dd/MM/yyyy. Unfortunately it doesn't work, the validation fails with any date format I try. Initially I thought the problem was the regex I use for testing, but after doing some tests I'm pretty sure it works.

What am I missing? Here is my code (I copy the relevant parts only), please help me to understand what I did wrong:

bean Articolo (N.B:this class is nested within model class NewEditArticle, below)

```
@Entity
@Table (name="Articolo")
public class Articolo {

    @Column (name="Data")
    @Temporal (TemporalType.DATE) //match the data type used in DB
    @IsValidDate //check date format is dd/MM/yyyy (custom validator)
    private Date data;
```

class IsValidDate

```
@Documented //mandatory
@Constraint (validatedBy= DateValidator.class) //this class contains the validation logic
@Retention (RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) //mandatory
public @interface IsValidDate {

    //error message
    String message() default "Please insert date in format dd/mm/yyyy";

    Class <?>[] groups() default {}; //mandatory

    Class <? extends Payload> [] payload () default {}; //mandatory
}
```

class DateValidator

```
public class DateValidator implements ConstraintValidator <IsValidDate, Date > {

    @Override
    public void initialize(IsValidDate isValidDate) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Date data, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {

        //convert Date data to String
        String dateString=data.toString();

        //format dd/MM/yyyy
        String regex="(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/((19|20)\\d\\d)";


        if (dateString.matches(regex)){
            return true;
        }

        //if date doesn't match regex, return error message from IsValidDate
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

model class

```
public class NewEditArticolo {

    //ATTRIBUTES

    @Valid  //requested to trigger validation of bean Articolo
    private Articolo articolo;

    private List<Area> ListaArea;
    private List<Cucina> ListaCucina;
    private List<Prezzo> ListaPrezzo;
    private List<Voto> ListaVoto;
    private List<String> ListaImg;


    //METHODS

    //CONSTRUCTOR

    //create article model without ID number
    //used in controller POST method
    public NewEditArticolo () {

        populateLists();
    }

    //create Article model based on ID number
    //if ID=0 (new Article), creates empty model
    //used in controller GET method
    public NewEditArticolo(int ID) throws SQLException {

        // call DAOArticolo.select only if article already exists
        if (ID != 0) {
            DAOArticolo DAOart = new DAOArticolo();
            articolo = DAOart.select(ID);
        }

        populateLists();

    }
```

Controller

```
public String editArticle ( Model model,
                                @Valid @ModelAttribute (value="nea") NewEditArticolo nea, //create NewEditArticolo object, autowire attributes from ArticleManager.jsp, add to model and validate
                                BindingResult result, //collect validation errors
                                @RequestParam (value="submit") String submit){ //get input value from ArticleManager.jsp

        Articolo articolo1=nea.getArticolo();

        DAOArticolo daoArt = new DAOArticolo();

        //if validation fails, return form to display validation errors
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("VALIDATION FAILED");
            return "ArticleManager";
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("VALIDATION WAS SUCCESFULL");
        }
```

Spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Do you actually  have a bean-validation implementation on your classpath... Without it nothing will happen.

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Comment: Not really, I'm not sure what you mean with a bean validation implementation...can you please explain more?

Comment: I added in the post my Spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without Regex. Spring has `@DateTimeFormat` annotation. In your model do the following.

```
@NotNull(message = "Please enter Birth Date")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date birthDate;
```

You can add your custom error messages. Create `message.properties` under resources folder. Inside in this file:

```
typeMismatch=Invalid date format
```

The important point is adding this to configuration class.

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return messageSource;
}
```

Comment: With the annotation-based validation you suggest, I always get the default error message, like if the message.properties file is ignored. My guess is, custom error messages don't work for validation of nested objects, as in my case (bean class Article is a field of model class NewEditArticle, which is validated in the controller class and auto-wired to the form).